# Assembling an array without looping in R

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

Suppose there are two matrices `A` and `B`:

```
(A <- mdat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), nrow = 4, ncol = 3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12

(B <- mdat <- matrix(rev(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)), nrow = 4, ncol = 3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   12    8    4
[2,]   11    7    3
[3,]   10    6    2
[4,]    9    5    1
```

I want to create array `C` defined as below:

```
C <- array(0, dim=c(4,3,3))
for(i in 1:ncol(A))
for(j in 1:ncol(B))
   C[, i, j] = A[,i] + B[,j]
```

How can this be done nicely without looping?

Comment: Your example doesn't run. Your loop is not properly specified and `C` doesn't exist to be assigned to.

Comment: I think you need something from the 'apply' family:  
- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html  
- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html  
Look at the 'see also' section for similar items.

Comment: @thelatemail Forgot one line of code. Just added now.

Comment: @AChervony How to convert `apply(A, 2, '+', B)` to the intended result?

Comment: @Psidom beat me to the punch. See their answer (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct array with the desired dimension attribute with `apply` method (from your comment but switch the positions of A and B):

```
array(apply(B, 2, "+", A), c(4,3,3))

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   17   21
[2,]   13   17   21
[3,]   13   17   21
[4,]   13   17   21

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    9   13   17
[2,]    9   13   17
[3,]    9   13   17
[4,]    9   13   17

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    9   13
[2,]    5    9   13
[3,]    5    9   13
[4,]    5    9   13
```

Answer (score 4):

Repeat each matrix's columns, then add and reset the dimensions:

```
out <- A[,rep(1:ncol(A),3)] + B[,rep(1:ncol(B),each=3)]
dim(out) <- c(4,3,3)

identical(out,C)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Would that work ?

```
i_vec <- rep(1:ncol(A),each  = ncol(B))
j_vec <- rep(1:ncol(B),ncol(A))
C <- array(0, dim=c(4,3,3))
Map(function(i,j){C[,i,j] <<- A[,i] + B[,j]},i_vec,j_vec)

# > C
# , , 1
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   13   17   21
# [2,]   13   17   21
# [3,]   13   17   21
# [4,]   13   17   21
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    9   13   17
# [2,]    9   13   17
# [3,]    9   13   17
# [4,]    9   13   17
# 
# , , 3
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    9   13
# [2,]    5    9   13
# [3,]    5    9   13
# [4,]    5    9   13
```